# Concatenate one row of a 2D vector into another row in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, concatenation, stdvector

I have a 2D vector as follows -

```
vector <vector<int> > v;
v.push_back({1, 2, 3});
v.push_back({4, 5});
v.push_back({6, 7, 8});

/*
row 0 - 1 2 3
row 1 - 4 5
row 2 - 6 7 8 
*/
```

I want to concatenate row 1 at the end of row 0 with minimum possible operations, such that the final 2D vector becomes this -

```
/*
row 0 - 1 2 3 4 5
row 1 - 6 7 8
*/
```

This was my algorithm which is **not efficient**-

```
1) create a temporary 1D vector 't'.
2) push_back all the elements of row 2 into 't'.
3) erase row 1 using v.erase(v.begin()+1);
4) insert 't' at the end of row 0 - v[0].insert(v[0].end(), t.begin(), t.end()).
```

Is there an efficient way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
v[0].insert(v[0].end(), v[1].begin(), v[1].end());
v[1].swap(v[2]);
v.pop_back();
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding at the top: `v[0].reserve(v[0].size() + v[1].size());` as this will prevent multiple reallocations during insert. Reserving first ensures at most one reallocation.

Comment: Also, a `move` would be better than a `swap` since `v[2]` can be garbage.

Comment: @cdhowie `insert` shouldn't perform multiple reallocations here, as it knows up front how many elements it would need to add.

Comment: @cigien The problem statement specifically calls for the contents of `v[2]` to be transferred to `v[1]`.

Comment: Right, but you don't need to transfer the contents of `v[1]` to `v[2]`. That's wasted work.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik How would that be possible unless `vector::insert` does its own reservation only if `last - first` is well-formed? If it doesn't know how many items are in the source range, it doesn't know how much space to reserve. I can't find any documentation stating that `vector::insert` on a range is required to reallocate at most one time when the source range iterators satisfy LegacyRandomAccessIterator.

Comment: @cdhowie It's not at all uncommon to dispatch on the iterator category. That's what `std::iterator_traits::iterator_category` is for.